# Dictionary update sequence element #10 has length 0; 2 is required

Tags: python, dictionary

The same error has been repeating endlessly :(

Code:

```
def query():
    query = input("Please insert your query here:\n")
    with open("TroubleShootingKey.txt") as f:
        dictq = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1)for x in f)
        print(dictq)
        found =False
        for k, v in dictq.items():
            if k in query:
                found = True
                print(v)

        if not found:
            print("sorry, we didn't get that")

query()
```

...

This is the syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/Naoman/Desktop/Naoman's Work/Computer Science/CA Final week/CA.6.py", line 42, in <module>
    query()
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/Naoman/Desktop/Naoman's Work/Computer Science/CA Final week/CA.6.py", line 31, in query
    dictq = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1)for x in f)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #10 has length 0; 2 is required
```

...

And this is the file is opened up (notepad):

turned Charge it

volume Change it to sound/normal mode

camera Remove the material blocking the lens

water Aloow the phone to dry

overheating Allow the phone to cool down in a cool environment

internet This is because you are not in a coverage area, try changing your location to catch a signal

wifi There are two ways to fix this problem, Firstly remove data my

storage Good, you are able to cool down in a cool environment

frozen Remove the battery and place it back to restart the phone

software Unfortunately, the only way to fix the problem is to reset the phone

Comment: Ick, *please* don't use the same name for global and local variables.

Comment: If you use `split( , 1)` that usually means you *really* wanted `.partition()`, that may obviate your error.

Comment: Don't edit "solved" into your question -- you mark something solved by accepting an answer, ie. clicking the checkbox next to it. If none of the answers posted by others helped, add your own. (Part of being a Q&A knowledge base, not a discussion board, is that we try to rate and improve both questions and answers; if you edit your chosen answer into your question, even in the title, that question is no longer independent of the answer, removing the community's ability to express their own preference re: answers separately from that of the person asking the question).

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you reached the end of the file.

You can add a

```
try:
    ...
except ValueError:
    ...
```

block around your code to just stop in this case (with a `break`).

Answer (score 0):

`split(None, 1)` on an empty string will return an empty list, which could be the reason for this error. You could reproduce the error with following snippet:

```
dict(x.split(None, 1) for x in [''])
```

A potential fix is to avoid calling `split()` on empty lines

```
dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f if x)
```